# Svelte template - Typescript discriminated union - Error 2322

Tags: typescript, svelte, discriminated-union

I have a Svelte template which has conditional output of subcomponent based on a object property. Even though the object property is uniquely identifying the type of object, the compiler complains with ts 2322.

```
//App.ts
<script lang="ts">
    import type {CheckboxData, LabelData} from 'Types.js';
    import Checkbox from 'Checkbox.svelte';
    import Label from 'Label.svelte';
    
    const tags = (CheckboxData | LabelData)[
                new CheckboxData(), new LabelData()
    ]   
</script>

{#each tags as tag}
    {#if tag.type === "CHECKBOX"}
        <Checbkox data={tag}/> // ts 2322 LabelData is not assignable to CheckboxData
    {:else if tag.type === "LABEL"}
        <Label data={tag}/>
    {/if}
{/each}
//end App.ts

// Types.ts
export class CheckboxData {
    type: "CHECKBOX";
    checked:boolean;
    name:string;
}

export class LabelData {
    type: "LABEL";
    text:string;
    for:string;
}
// end Types.ts

// Checbkox.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import type {CheckboxData} from 'Types.js';
    export let data:CheckboxData;
</script>

<checkbox checked={data.checked} name={data.name}></checkbox>
// end Checkbox.svelte

// Label.svelte
<script lang="ts">
    import type {LabelData} from 'Types.js';
    export let data:Label;
</script>

<label for={data.for}>{data.text}</label>
// end Label.svelte
```

Comment: This is only for info.. But there is a typo in `const tags = (CheckboxData | LabelData)[
                new ***ChecbkoxData***(), new LabelData()
    ] `

Comment: Is `const tags ....` an array of 2 elements?

Answer (score 0):

I missed the **literal** part of the "equation", discrimination works if the property is defined like this:

```
type: "CHECKBOX"
```

not

```
type:string = "CHECKBOX"
```